# curve_fit: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

Estou com problemas com o `curve_fit` do scipy, o erro que sai me diz que não consegue multiplicar sequencia por `float`, estou tentando criar uma sequência com base na função que eu defini e com os valores encontrado do curve_fit, mas ele me dá esse erro, não sei o que está acontecendo, pois é exatamente a mesma coisa que tem na documentação do curve_fit, que qndo eu rodo no iPython ele corre de boa... Alguém pode ajudar? Segue o código:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import numpy as np  
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit  

X1 = [0.0,0.55,1.1,2.1,3.15,5.05,7.05,9.05,11.25]  
I1 = [397.,360.,342.,282.,249.,203.,159.,126.,102.]  

X2 = [0.0,6.2,12.01,18.21,28.51,38.91]  
I2 = [324.,292.,256.,223.,182.,153.]  

def func(x, I0, k):  
    return I0 * np.exp( -k * x )  

popt_1, pcov_1 = curve_fit(func,X1,I1)  
popt_2, pcov_2 = curve_fit(func,X2,I2)  

print popt_1, popt_2     


Y1 = func(X1, *popt_1)  
Y2 = func(X2, *popt_2)  

plt.plot(X1,Y1)  
plt.plot(X1,I1,'o')  
plt.show()  

plt.plot(X2,Y2)  
plt.plot(X2,I2,'o')  
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que apesar de listas normais do Python e "arrays" do numpy ambos funcionarem como sequências, e poderem ser passadas nas chamadas para o `plt`, elas não são a mesma coisa.

Em particular, uma para lista comum do Python, que é como você colocou seus dados nas variáveis `X1`..`I2`,o operador de multiplicação `*` só está definido para inteiros, e o que ele faz é criar uma nova lista, concatenando uma lista com ela mesma n vezes. Ou seja:

```py
In [3]: a = [0, 1, 2]                                                                                       

In [4]: a * 3                                                                                               
Out[4]: [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
```

E para esse uso do operador, é fácil ver que não faz sentido a multiplicação por um número decimal (no caso, float), que você está fazendo na linha `return I0 * np.exp( -k * x )`

Já para arrays do np, todos os operadores são sobrecarregados, e estão definidos para, em uma operaçao de um array com um escalar, gerar um novo array realizando  operação em cada elemento do array:

```py
In [8]: b = np.array([0, 1, 2])                                                                             

In [9]: b * 3                                                                                               
Out[9]: array([0, 3, 6])
```

Ou seja, tudo o que você precisa fazer no seu código é transformar seus valores em arrays do numpy, antes de executar a `func` e plotar os resultados:

```py
import numpy as np
...

X1 = np.array([0.0,0.55,1.1,2.1,3.15,5.05,7.05,9.05,11.25])
I1 = np.array([397.,360.,342.,282.,249.,203.,159.,126.,102.]) 

X2 = np.array([0.0,6.2,12.01,18.21,28.51,38.91])
I2 = np.array([324.,292.,256.,223.,182.,153.])
...
```